# How to pipe something between Readable and Writable stream in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I have two streams: `readable` incoming and `writable` outgoing.

In initial configuration I just piped them and it worked fine:

[image]

However in my setup I need to do something with data passing through. I implemented a simple logic which does

```
readable.on("data", (data) => {
  const modifiedData = modify(data);
  writable.write(modifiedData)
})
readable.on("finish", () => writable.end())
```

As you can see, these streams are not aware of their existence and I need to manually end writable stream.

How can I create something which can be piped between these streams so I can do
[image]

```
readable.pipe(myLogic).pipe(writable)
```

Comment: Take a look at [transform streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#implementing-a-transform-stream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@robertklep suggested to use Node's Transform stream and this is what you are looking for if you want to implement such "interceptor".